# returning NaN while designing a stopwatch

Tags: angular, ionic2

THIS WORKED
i am trying to create a stop watch, on clicking start button it should start and on reset everything should be 0

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html'
})

export class LoginPage {

public time = 0;
    public running = 0;
constructor(   ) { }

starttime(){
        console.log("timer started");
        if( this.running == 0){
            this.running = 1;
            this.adder()
        }else{
            this.running = 0;
        }
   }

    reset(){
        console.log("timer reset");
        this.running = 0;
        this.time = 0;

    }
    adder(){

    console.log("timer incrementor");
    if(this.running == 1){
        setTimeout(()=>{ 
            this.time++;
            var mins = Math.floor(this.time/10/60);
            var sec = Math.floor(this.time / 10 );
            var tens = this.time/10;

            console.log( mins + ':' +  sec  + ':' + tens);   
            this.adder()  

        },100)
    }

}

    }

}

 <button ion-button block (click)="starttime()">starttime</button>
        <button ion-button block (click)="reset()">reset</button>
{{display the timer here}}
```

i need the timer to get started and should be visible in real time, on stop it should get reset to 0, i tried the above code but it returned "NaN"
could someone help me

[image]

Comment: What is returning `NaN` ?

Comment: console.log( mins + ':' +  sec  + ':' + tens); is returning NaN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
  setTimeout(function(){
                this.time++;
                var mins = Math.floor(this.time/10/60);
                var sec = Math.floor(this.time / 10 );
                var tens = this.time/10;

                console.log( mins + ':' +  sec  + ':' + tens);              

            },100)
```

to

```
  setTimeout(()=>{ // <------------change here
                this.time++;
                var mins = Math.floor(this.time/10/60);
                var sec = Math.floor(this.time / 10 );
                var tens = this.time/10;

                console.log( mins + ':' +  sec  + ':' + tens);              

            },100)
```

Since you are using `function` instead of `=>` your `this` is not refering to the component

Answer (score 0):

You've never set `this.time`. You have a `reset()` method which does so, but you do not call it. So `this.time` is undefined, which when passed through `Math.floor`, returns `NaN`. Set `this.time` in the constructor, or call `reset()` before you start the timer.

Comment: `public time = 0;`

Comment: u mean like this constructor( ) {this.time }, and actually i have public time = 0;